# Could not read public directory. Remove links and shortcuts and try again. (Firebase)

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I was stepping through this tutorial:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#0

On step 9 it asks you to execute `firebase deploy` but when I try to do it I get the error message:

> Could not read public directory. Remove links and shortcuts and try again.

I don't know what it means by links and shortcuts as far as I can tell there nothing in this folder but plain old files.

The folder I'm trying to deploy is the `web` folder which should contain the completed sample.

Note that as per the instructions the `storage.rules` was updated with the name of the bucket and the index.html was updated with the firebase snippet.

The firebase.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database-rules.json"
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "./",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "database-rules.json",
      "storage.rules"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas as to what this error could be? Is there any way to get more detailed information?

Answer (score 4):

You should use debug command like this:  **firebase deploy --debug**  , this can help you find out what cause this problem easily and clearly.

Answer (score 3):

In my case a temp emacs file was causing the issue:

```
$ firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'xxxx-42402'...

i  deploying database, hosting
✔  database: rules ready to deploy.
i  hosting: preparing public directory for upload...

Error: Could not read public directory. Remove links and shortcuts and try again.
RooseveltPwnsU:xxxx xrdawson$ ls -la public/
total 3840
-rw-r--r--   1 xrdawson  staff     5122 Feb 13 12:52 #index.html#
drwxr-xr-x  15 xrdawson  staff      510 Feb 13 14:40 .
lrwxr-xr-x   1 xrdawson  staff       35 Feb  6 14:12 .#index.html -> xrdawson@RooseveltPwnsU.local.67168
```

Saving the file index.html inside emacs resolved the issue for me!

Answer (score 2):

**The problem was firebase-debug.log**

The issue turned out to be unrelated to the configuration. The issue actually turned out to be a file permission issue with `firebase-debug.log`. I solved the issue by copying everything but that file into a new folder and deploying the new folder.

**How I found out**

Since there is no way to tell that's the issue from the error message above. I thought it would still be useful to walk you through the process I used to uncover the issue.

**Windows 10**

First I want to mention that I'm on a Windows 10 computer, I don't know if that's relevant, but just in case it is I thought I'd mention it.

**1. Compare to a working project**

In order to have a baseline / frame of reference, I created a new project using the `firebase init` command.

I then tried to deploy that. That was successful, so I knew deployment in general worked.

**2. Use the same firebase.json**

I then took the auto generated `firebase.json` file from the working deployment folder and replaced the firebase.json file in the project folder where the deployment wasn't working.

When I tried to deployed it still didn't work.

**3. Remove permissions**

At this point I suspected it was a permission issue. So I decided to zip up the folder and then unzip it to a different folder. Then try to deploy the new folder.

The theory being that the permissions would be wiped out in the process.

When I tried to zip the file I got a file permission error message. The name of the file with the issue was `firebase-debug.log`. That's the file that automatically generated when you try to deploy.

> `firebase-debug.log` is automatically generated by the `firebase deploy` command

So instead of zipping and unzipping I just copied all the files except `firebase-debug.log` and tried to deploy that.

**Success**

It worked!

*Still haven't figured out how to actually delete that damn file though.*

Answer (score 1):

After a rough search with no solution, I tried npm i then firebase deploy. Yay! it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and in my case  it was `firebase serve` that was locking the file. Stopping that process allowed the `firebase deploy` to run successfully.

I suspect its actually because two separate instances of firebase are trying to write to the same log file and `serve` holds a lock while running.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the `firebase-debug.log` file and entered the following command:

`firebase deploy --only funtions` but `firebase deploy` will also work.

in my project i needed to deploy, but if you need to test locally try `firebase serve` or `firebase serve --only functions` or `firebase serve --only functions,hosting` based on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There's a possibility that you are in `/functions` when you want to deploy. In my case I run the `firebase deploy --only functions:FOOBAR` command in root (out of functions) folder and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and rerunning `npm install` fixed the problem for me.